# JNDI: Cannot instantiate class: org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory

Tags: jboss, jms, jndi, factory

There is a similar question already on the board, nonetheless the solution code suggested is not working for me. I want to implement a simple chat program (jms pub/sub) by using Java Messaging Service and a Wildfly 10 Application Server. I configured and started the server in eclipse (status: Started,Synchronized). When I compile my programm consisting of only one class, this error message occurs:

`javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Cannot instantiate class: org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory [Root exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory] at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(Unknown Source) at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(Unknown Source) at javax.naming.InitialContext.init(Unknown Source) at javax.naming.InitialContext.<init>(Unknown Source) at Chat.<init>(Chat.java:55) at Chat.main(Chat.java:128) Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source) at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source) at com.sun.naming.internal.VersionHelper12.loadClass(Unknown Source) at com.sun.naming.internal.VersionHelper12.loadClass(Unknown Source) ... 6 more`

I dont think that there is anything wrong with the JNDI properties in the code (I tried several derivates):

```
Properties jndiProps = new Properties();
jndiProps.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,         
"org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory");
jndiProps.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL,"remote://localhost:9090");
jndiProps.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "testuser");
jndiProps.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "testpassword");
jndiProps.put("jboss.naming.client.ejb.context", true);
Context ctx = new InitialContext(jndiProps);
```

The wildfly 10 jar is added to the project path, as well as the jms.jar

What else can cause the error?

Edit:

I tried to use maven because I thought some jars are not recognized. I added wildfly10 and jms to my pom file:

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
      <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
      <groupId>mannheim</groupId>
      <artifactId>hello</artifactId>
      <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>



      <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
            <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.wildfly</groupId>
            <artifactId>wildfly-ejb-client-bom</artifactId>
            <version>10.0.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
      </dependencies>
    </project>
```

In the pom file it says for both dependencies:

**Missing artifact javax.jms:jms:jar:1.1**

So there are still problems with recognizing the jar.files i guess?

Comment: Have you tried to add 'jndiProps.put( Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES, "org.jboss.ejb.client.naming" );' on your jndi properties?

Comment: i added it to the properties but still gets me this error: "javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Cannot instantiate class: org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory"

Comment: I think you are missing jboss-client.jar file? it is under wildfly/bin/client

Answer (score 0):

Refer [sample example of Wildfly 10](https://github.com/wildfly/quickstart/blob/10.x/helloworld-jms/src/main/java/org/jboss/as/quickstarts/jms/HelloWorldJMSClient.java).

Comment: still the same error. I tried to use maven now but i get another error message in the pom file. Maybe that is the reason (see edited post)